# Creating Excel VBA code for if Checkbox is Checked display "X" in Cell K21

Tags: vba, excel

I have checkboxes in Excel that are used to track if a document were completed or not.

Unfortunately, the checkboxes are so small, they are overlooked.

I thought I would try to use code to make this process easier to check.

What is the VBA code:

```
If Checkbox is Checked - then Display X in Cell K21

If Checkbox is not checked - then *do not * Display X in Cell K21
```

Image of what I want it to look like when Checked:

[image: Image of what I want it to look like when Checked]

Image of what I want it to look like when Not Checked:

[image: Image of what I want it to look like when Not Checked]

Comment: Link each checkbox to a cell, then use a formula in (eg) K21 to determine whether or not to show the X

Comment: What formula would I use that can reference the Check Box?

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
Sub BoxCheck()

    If ActiveSheet.Shapes("TestBox").ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then
    'Make sure name "TestBox" matches name of your checkbox
        ActiveSheet.Range("K21").Value = "X"
    Else:
        ActiveSheet.Range("K21").Value = ""
    End If

End Sub
```

Make sure you set the name of your checkbox:

[image: TestBox]

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Range("K21").Value = IIf(ActiveSheet.Shapes("TestBox").ControlFormat.Value = 1, "X", "")`